# Does convergence of one series imply convergence of another series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let's assume that $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$$ is convergent. Does it imply that $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {a_{n}}{n^{1/2}} $$ is
>   a)convergent
>   b)absolutely convergent     ???
>   Please, give a proof or counterexample.

I've looked for some counterexamples but without any positive results.

EDIT1: I thought of absolute convergence obviosuly.
EDIT:
I'm sorry I forgot to mention, what was my solution.

Since I know that:

Sorry, I forgot to mention that.
Since I know that: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$$ is convergent,
I can tell that that it satisfies Cauchy's condition $$ for   E>0   
 \left| \left(a_{1} + a_{2} + a_{3} + a_{4} + ...\right)  \right| <E$$ , so then if I multiply it by $$\frac {1}{n^{1/2}}$$ I have got:
$$\frac{1}{n^{1/2}} \left| \left(a_{1} + a_{2} + a_{3} + a_{4} + ...\right)  \right| $$
and then for enough big n it is still smaller than E, because  $$\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}$$ goes to 0 in infinity.
Is it correct?

Comment: For one of your questions, consider $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: The question is equivalent to this: Assume that the sequence $(s_n)$ is convergent. Does it imply that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (s_n-s_{n-1})/n^{1/2}$ is convergent? You may find this easier to answer (hint: partial summation). To prove the claimed equivalence, let $s_n$ be the $n$th partial sum of $\sum a_n$.

Comment: When you say *unconditionally convergent*, are you drawing a distinction between that and *absolutely convergent*?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that.
Since I know that: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$$ is convergent,
I can tell that that it satisfies Cauchy's condition $$ for E>0 \left| \left(a_{1} + a_{2} + a_{3} + a_{4} + ...\right)  \right| <E$$ , so then if I multiply it by $${1}{n^{1/2}}$$ I have got:
$${1}{n^{1/2}} \left| \left(a_{1} + a_{2} + a_{3} + a_{4} + ...\right)  \right| $$
and then for enough big n it is still smaller than E, because  $${1}{n^{1/2}}$$ goes to 0 in infinity.
Is it correct?

Comment: @kontiki : You can't just multiply $|a_1 + a_2 + \cdots |$ by $\frac 1{n^{1/2}}$ ; each term has to be multiplied by a different coefficient, namely $a_n$ has to be multiplied by $\frac 1{n^{1/2}}$. Cauchy's condition tells you a property of the partial sums, not of the whole series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magic words are: [Abel's test.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test) This will help you with convergence. For absolute convergence, you should be able to give a counterexample.